# PHP Regular Expression Problem

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a string which I store book pages. It's something like this:

```
///0///
Page1 Text
///1///
Page2 Text
///2///
Page3 Text
///3///
```

I want to extract page texts (Page1 Text, Page2 Text, Page3 Text). Here is the Regular Expression which is am using:

```
$format = "%///\d*///(.*)///\d*///%";
preg_replace_callback($format, "process_page", $text);
```

According to [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) I can use other character than / in the start and end of the expression. So I used % to simplify my pattern, so I don't have to use escape character like this \/

It seems okay to me, but it return nothing. Can somebody please tell me where is the problem?

Comment: Why not to delete every line that begins with `///`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) might be a better option for you:

```
$text = '
Page1 Text
///1///
Page2 Text
///2///
Page3 Text
';

$format = "%///\d+///%";
$arr = preg_split($format, $text);

// $arr = Array
// ( 
//     [0] => Page1 Text
//
//     [1] => 
// Page2 Text
// 
//     [2] => 
// Page3 Text
// )
```

Each page is now in it's own array element.

Comment: Works like a charm. I'm playing with this more than 10 hour with no result. preg_split is fantastic function which unfortunately I was not familiar with. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the [`s` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php): `$format = "%///\d*///(.*)///\d*///%s";`

> s (PCRE_DOTALL)
>
> If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the setting of this modifier.

I'm not sure what you're tryingto do but personally I wouldn't use regex for this. you know the *exact* string to look for (eg `///4///`) and from there the end string (`///5///` or end of file). A simle substr with strpos might be a better option.

Comment: Actually a book can contain up until 1000 pages. Regular expression is much easier.

Comment: @Mani, what do you mean with "easier"? Is it faster?

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like `preg_spilt` (see Tim Cooper's answer).

But for your RegEx, try this:

```
$format = "%///\d+///(.*?)(?=///\d+///)%s";
```

With Look-around assertion and `s`-modifier.

Comment: I am newbie in Regular Expression. I learn about Assertion recently, But I forgot to use it here. Thank for the tip.